# How to show confirm message when form have been changed?

Tags: javascript

I have a form which contains a lot of elements. Whenever I change an element (for example, a textbox or a text area), and then I go to another page, the browser will display a confirmation message for me to confirm if I'm sure I want to exit.

Here is my simple form, not the real one:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So, when I edit the FirstName or the LastName and go to leave the page, the confirmation message will appear. But when I delete all the changes and go to leave the page, the confirmation message won't appear anymore. And because I also use my form when I insert and edit, I cannot just simply compare between the input fname and "" (for example), but I need to compare the original data and the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onfocus="fnm=this.defaultValue;" onblur="if(fnm!=this.value)confirm('Changed!');" >
```

may Help!

Comment: this.defaultValue might be a better value to test

Comment: Yes sir! You are right...